# The eigenvalue of $\lambda^2I+\lambda A+B$ where $A,B$ are positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A,B$ are positive definite matrix. Consider the matrix $\lambda^2I+\lambda A+B$, I want to prove if this matrix has Kernel, we need to have  $Re(\lambda)<0$

---

I don't know how to start, since the eigenvalue of $A+B$ is not determined

Comment: Hint: Suppose $\vec{v}$ is in the kernel.  Then, what do you know about $$\vec{v}^T(\lambda^2I+\lambda A+B)\vec{v}?$$

Comment: @MichaelBurr it should be $|\lambda|^2$ instead of $\lambda^2$, if I understand what u mean

Comment: @MichaelBurr oh, I see thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if for any nonzero vector $\vec{v}$, $\vec{v}^TA\vec{v}>0$.

Suppose that the kernel is nontrivial and let $\vec{v}$ be a nonzero vector in the kernel.  Then,
$$
\vec{v}^T(\lambda^2I+\lambda A+B)\vec{v}=\vec{0}
$$
and the equality simplifies to
$$
a_2\lambda^2+a_1\lambda+a_0=0
$$
where each $a_i$ is positive.

This polynomial (in $\lambda$) has no positive real roots via Descartes' rule of signs (or the derivative is always positive).  Since $a_0$ is not zero, the polynomial doesn't have a root at $0$.  Suppose the polynomial had a complex root $z=x+iy$.  Since $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2$ are all real, $\overline{z}$ is also a root of this polynomial.  Moreover, the polynomial can be factored as:
$$
a_2(\lambda-z)(\lambda-\overline{z})=a_2\lambda^2-a_2(z+\overline{z})\lambda+a_2z\overline{z}.
$$
The coefficient of $\lambda$ is $-2Re(z)=a_1$, so $Re(z)<0$.